# Calling same plsql Procedure more than once in a package parallely

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper

Have one plsql package "OMX_BEACON_MIG" where am calling

```
PROCEDURE handle_NR_Site(
    i_old_plan_inst_id NUMBER,
    i_new_plan_inst_id NUMBER,
    i_old_act_id       NUMBER,
    i_new_act_id       NUMBER )
```

To process action ids i.e., if i have 4 action id's then i am calling this procedure 4 times since `" i_old_plan_inst_id" , "i_new_plan_inst_id","i_old_act_id","i_new_act_id"` are different for every action.

Is there any solution where i can call this procedure only once  and all the 4 actions are processed ate once?

Or is there anyway to carry out calling this function parallely instead of calling one by one?
Please guide.

Comment: You could create 4 ad-hoc scheduled jobs, but if your code needs to continue once the 4 jobs have completed, you need to write some monitoring code that can check for when the jobs have completed, and you'd have to handle the case where one or more of them fail. Alternatively, you could look at the handle_nr_site procedure and see if there's any way of converting it to handle multiple actions at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has a very nice utility dbms_scheduler to run jobs in parallel . You can call the below function four times with different parameters to execute them in parallel.

```
dbms_scheduler.create_job(job_name => dbms_scheduler.generate_job_name('MY_JOB_'),
   job_type => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
   job_action => 'begin  handle_NR_Site(i_old_plan_inst_id => param1, i_new_plan_inst_id => param2, i_old_act_id => param3, i_new_act_id => param4 ); end;',
   comments => 'Thread 1 descriptionn',
   enabled => true,
   auto_drop => true);
```

The jobs will run in background. Query the table `DBA_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS` to get the execution status.

For more detailed explanation check the link:
https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/scheduler-10g